# Pause at top and bottom continuous vertical scroll HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an embedded HTML page containing a single table of event results. I have found the code below which perfectly gives a continuous scroll, however I which to be able to pause for say 10 seconds at both the top and bottom before continuing.

How do I intercept the top and bottom and insert the pause?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
/*
Advanced window scroller script-
By JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
Over 200+ free JavaScripts here!
*/
var currentpos = 0, alt = 1, curpos1 = 0, curpos2 = -1

function initialize() {
  startit()
}

function scrollwindow() {
  if (document.all)
    temp = document.body.scrollTop
  else
    temp = window.pageYOffset
  if (alt == 0)
    alt = 1
  else
    alt = 0
  if (alt == 0)
    curpos1 = temp
  else
    curpos2 = temp
  if (curpos1 != curpos2) {
    if (document.all)
      currentpos = document.body.scrollTop + 300
    else
      currentpos = window.pageYOffset + 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
  }
  else {
    currentpos = 0
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
  }
}

function startit() {
  setInterval("scrollwindow()", 25)
}

window.onload = initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `setInterval` is a basic javascript function, which runs a function every n-seconds, you set a global variable to capture that "interval", then cancel it when the user performs some action (click on a button).  Then resubmit the `setInterval` to start running in the future, or tie it back to another onClick event. An example would be to have a button that will toggle the `setInterval` on and off, which will act as a pause/run.

Below is an example of how you could set this up.  I have not tested it, so there may be some use cases that could cause issues.

```js
var myInterval = null;
function startit() {
  myInterval = setInterval("scrollwindow()", 25)
}
```

Then to cancel the interval:

```js
function stopInterval() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = null;
}
```

Example of how to toggle the interval on and off:

```js
function toggleInterval() {
  if ( myInterval ) {
    stopInterval();
  }
  else {
    startit();
  }
}
```

Then just add it to any html element, or a button.  This example is assuming the css is locked at the top of the scrollable pane so the user could always have access to click it.

```html
  <span onClick="toggleInterval()">Click to pause/continue scrolling.</span>

  <button onClick="toggleInterval()">Pause/Scroll</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not want to add stop / start buttons. Just a continuouse scroll but increasing the interval time when it reaches the bottom and then flips back to the top. This is just a single object (the HTML page) so I need to know a way to grab the top and bottom (0% and 100% I presume.

Comment: The example is using a toggle to start and stop the interval on user demand. You can use that same knowledge on how to control the interval to automate it like you were needing.

Comment: You can use javascript to monitor the container that is "growing".  When it has not grown for a period of time, the script can then scroll to the top of the page like you were wanting.  You can identify if the container is growing with jquery.  And jquery can also be used to reposition the page to the top.  It should be a rather simple function to write.  And to run it, you can also use interval to have it check every few seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next week but my knowledge of Javascript is near zero. The HTML is created totally by my own scripting from Delphi, simply creating a text file.

Comment: Sorry Blue but I am still drowning. There are many examples around with snippets for buttons or multiple section (skip to next after x) but I cannot find anything that will just work on a single element (table), pause at top scroll down at rate, pause at bottom repeat.  I just cannot figure out where to put the any intercept instructions